# Como mudar IMG(logo) do menu(header) ao rolar página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Tenho esse menu que possui uma imagem: logo.png, como mostra o código abaixo

```
<header  class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="grid-4">
            <img  src="img/logo.png">
        </a>
        <nav class="grid-12  menu header_menu">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="portfolio.html">Portfólio</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="contato.html">Contato</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>  
    </div>
</header>
```

Tenho outra imagem nomeada logo2.png, como faço pra trocar uma imagem pela outra quando rolar a página?

Já possuo o código javascript que também altera a cor de fundo do header de preto pra branco quando rolo a página.

Comment: Adicione um `id` no seu <img> e caso tenha feito uma condição tenta colocar essa linha dentro do if - `$("#minhaImagem").attr("src", "logo2.jpg"); ` vê se funciona

Comment: deu certo @Nathan, muito obrigado, já tinha procurado todas as formas diferentes, me serviu perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma, usando `$(window).scroll` e trocando a imagem com `.attr`. Veja:

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
      
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
   $("#imagem").attr("src", "http://www.completaweb.com.br/images/logo/logo-html5.png");
  } else {
   $("#imagem").attr("src", "http://susilsingh.com.np/img/skills/css3_logo.png");
  }      
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header  class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="grid-4">
            <img height="300" width="300" id="imagem"  src="http://susilsingh.com.np/img/skills/css3_logo.png">
        </a>
        <nav class="grid-12  menu header_menu">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="portfolio.html">Portfólio</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="contato.html">Contato</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>  
    </div>
</header>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at dignissim erat. Cras vulputate finibus sollicitudin. Duis id risus pretium, aliquet dolor in, auctor nibh. Nunc nunc urna, tincidunt eu lacus vitae, rhoncus convallis nibh. Sed ut odio justo. Proin luctus commodo mi, ut maximus tellus blandit at. Vivamus vitae dui euismod, suscipit risus sit amet, porttitor urna. Pellentesque eget pellentesque erat, eu tincidunt est. Vestibulum nunc erat, dictum vitae erat vitae, pretium pharetra diam. In fringilla, tortor quis lacinia finibus, lacus leo viverra felis, ac condimentum ipsum sapien vitae eros. Nulla facilisi.</p>
<p>space</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at dignissim erat. Cras vulputate finibus sollicitudin. Duis id risus pretium, aliquet dolor in, auctor nibh. Nunc nunc urna, tincidunt eu lacus vitae, rhoncus convallis nibh. Sed ut odio justo. Proin luctus commodo mi, ut maximus tellus blandit at. Vivamus vitae dui euismod, suscipit risus sit amet, porttitor urna. Pellentesque eget pellentesque erat, eu tincidunt est. Vestibulum nunc erat, dictum vitae erat vitae, pretium pharetra diam. In fringilla, tortor quis lacinia finibus, lacus leo viverra felis, ac condimentum ipsum sapien vitae eros. Nulla facilisi.</p>
<p>space</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at dignissim erat. Cras vulputate finibus sollicitudin. Duis id risus pretium, aliquet dolor in, auctor nibh. Nunc nunc urna, tincidunt eu lacus vitae, rhoncus convallis nibh. Sed ut odio justo. Proin luctus commodo mi, ut maximus tellus blandit at. Vivamus vitae dui euismod, suscipit risus sit amet, porttitor urna. Pellentesque eget pellentesque erat, eu tincidunt est. Vestibulum nunc erat, dictum vitae erat vitae, pretium pharetra diam. In fringilla, tortor quis lacinia finibus, lacus leo viverra felis, ac condimentum ipsum sapien vitae eros. Nulla facilisi.</p>
<p>space</p>

<p>space</p>
<p>space</p>
<p>space</p>
<p>space</p>
```